# Android - How to Create Intent to open the activity that displays the "Accounts & Sync settings" screen

Tags: android

I have seen the below log message when navigating to the Account & sync settings screen but I am confused as to how to create an Intent to navigate there.

```
INFO/ActivityManager(53): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.providers.subscribedfeeds/com.android.settings.ManageAccountsSettings }
```

I dont seem to have access to the ManageAccountsSettings for development.

I just wanted to create an Intent such as below, but I cant call out ManageAccountsSettings

```
Intent i =new Intent(this,ManageAccountsSettings.class);
//Then start the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this one (untested)

```
import android.provider.Settings;
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Excellent, I guess it is going to take me time to figure out where to look for Actions that can be used for Intents.
Thanks

Comment: Another cool trick:  if you add an extra to that intent called Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES with a value that is your account's authority, you can limit the accounts shown to just yours.  Note that the value has to be in a string array, it can't just be a string.

Comment: @maxpower47  maxpower47 this is illuminating, but please how do I get the Authorities of the Accounts?

Comment: @LisaAnne The authorities is an array of Strings, each of which reflects your ContentProvider's `android:authorities` attribute, as in `<provider android:authorities="..." />`.

Comment: I checked this answer several years ago, and it didn't work for the version of Android that was current that time.
But today I confirm that it does work for Android 6 and 7.1  
Moreover, addition of Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, as @maxpower47 suggested, allows to show to a User only my application's accounts.  
It's interesting that my application has several "providers", none of them is related to accounts. But "android:authorities" value of the first arbitrary selected provider did the trick!
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[]{MY_AUTHORITY});

Comment: From API Level 18 onwards you can also use: `intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[]{my_account_type});` if you don't have/want to use an authority.