# Navigate to account settings for a specific SyncAdapter account?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I want to open up the account settings for a specific SyncAdapter account. Is there an action and/or URI that can be passed into an Intent to navigate to this activity?

It seems like it'd be straightforward to navigate to the account settings (content providers to sync, etc) for a specific Account, especially given I created the account. (Note that I do not want to navigate to the list of Sync accounts with a SYNC_SETTINGS Intent, though maybe there is a hack, by navigating there first?)

Comment: do you want to open the sync adapter PrecerenceActivity? I think you can do it as you do for all the PreferenceActivity

Answer (score 2):

You can't navigate directly to an account, however you can navigate to the selection page filtered to show only your account types.  (always remember, there may be multiple accounts of your defined type)

See: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010241/633187 and notice the second comment by Maxpower47.